# parsing a string that ends

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a huge string. I need to extract a substring from that that huge string. The conditions are the string starts with either "TECHNICAL" or "JUSTIFY" or "ALIGN" and ends with a number( any number from 1 to 10) followed by  period and then followed by space. so for example, I have

string x = "This is a test, again I am testing TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing. 8. This is test again and again and again and again.";

so I need this

TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing.

I was wondering if someone has elegant solution for that.

I was trying to use the regular expression, but I guess I could not figure out the right expresion.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `@"((?:TECHNICAL|JUSTIFY|ALIGN).*?)(?:[1-9]|10)\. "`